# Compiling GMP for cross compiler problem

Tags: linux, gnu, gmp

I'm compiling gnu gmp for my mac/linux cross compiler but i'm getting this error:

```
In file included from ../gmp-impl.h:102,
                 from fib_table.c:4:
../fib_table.h:4: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
../fib_table.h:4: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘Error’
../fib_table.h:4: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘error’
../fib_table.h:4: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘data’
fib_table.c:7: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
fib_table.c:7: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘Error’
fib_table.c:7: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘error’
fib_table.c:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘data’
fib_table.c:107: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function
make[2]: *** [fib_table.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

when running "make"

My configure command is "./configure --prefix=/Users/daniel/gmp --build=i386-linux"

Comment: Daniel, did you run a `make clean`? Was your configure successful? What cross do you mean (what is the host - the machine on which compiler is started and what is the target - machine which will run this gmp)?

Comment: I'm compiling this gmp so i can compile a cross compiler for linux. i'm compiling this gmp on a mac

Comment: again - you must tell the cross compiler to configure script

Comment: :S no one has replied with an answer at all :S

Comment: Does it work without the `--build` option? Your problem may not have anything to do with this at all - and you might simply be asking how to compile GMP on a mac. Also, what version of GMP is this? A current, stable release?

Answer (score 1):

`make distclean` solved it for me